# ImageMagick (Magick.NET) 's Pdf to Jpg/Tiff operation gives me wrong color for CMYK to CMYK

Tags: c#, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, magick.net

**Issue**

When converting to Jpg/Tiff (CMYK), output images has different CMYK values for same areas from the input:

- (100)C become (76)C, (7)M, (14)Y
- (100)M become (87)M, (5)Y
- (100)Y become (85)Y
- (100)K become (72)C, (67)M, (67)Y, (88)K
- Pure white stays (0)C, (0)M, (0)Y, (0)K

**History**

- [My last wrong question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044125/need-to-rasterize-pdf-into-cmyk-image-for-printing-but-all-libraries-give-me-cm/63050028#63050028)
- [A not necessarily related question about IM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801633/php-imagick-cmyk-pdf-convert-to-jpg) and [a second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270389/imagemagick-promote-grays-to-cmyk-black).

**Sample code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ImageMagick;

namespace stackOVERFLOW
{
    class Sample
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            Rasterize("SOSample.pdf");
        }
        static void Rasterize(string input)
        {
            var settings = new MagickReadSettings
            {
                Density = new Density(300, 300),
                ColorSpace = ColorSpace.CMYK
            };
            var images = new MagickImageCollection();
            images.Read(input, settings);
            images[0].Format = MagickFormat.Jpg; //or .Tiff
            images[0].Write(input[0..^4] + ".jpg"); // or ".tiff"
        }
    }
}
```

**Input**

- [Input PDF](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/files/4965415/SOSample.pdf) (CMYK with pure C, M, Y, K and white areas)

**Output**

- [JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKvK2.jpg) (Separation: [C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bfLx.jpg) | [M](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zijW.jpg) | [Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7cQ7.jpg) | [K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dProW.jpg) )

**Code for channel separation** (used for output sample)

```
List<String> colors = new List<String> { "C", "M", "Y", "K" };
int n = 0;
foreach (IMagickImage<ushort> channel in images[0].Separate(Channels.All))
{
    channel.Negate();
    channel.Write(input[0..^4] + "_" + colors[n] + ".jpg");
    n++;
}
```

**Interpretation of the problem**

When converting to PNG (RGB) colors looks right for RGB, the feeling is that it's been converted to RGB before CMYK.

```
images[0].Format = MagickFormat.Png;
images[0].Write(input[0..^4] + ".png");
```

**Purpose**

It's for offset plate setting purpose, it's important the black to stay pure black (and the CMYK values in general) for many reasons including color quality, 1 color printing (B&W), etc.

**Finally**

- Is there any way to get the expected result with Magick.net?
- Is there any way to get the expected result with Ghostscript itself?
- If you know any way to get CMYK raster image from a PDF, help me, I'm open for any language, etc.

**Aditional Information:**

Using Magick.NET-Q16-x64 v7.21.0 NuGet package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dlemstra** (Magick.net) answered me in GitHub this output is because PDF decoder of ImageMagick used the option `-dUseCIEColor`, they will fix it in the next release. For more information check the [GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/discussions/704).

Answer (score 1):

Well, Ghostscript produces the correct output, so I'd have to guess ImageMagick is doing something to it. Or possibly using the wrong device. Obviously I don't know what IM does to get Ghostscript to turn a PDF file into 'something else'.

This:

gs -sDEVICE=jpegcmyk -o out.jpg cmyk.pdf

produces a JPEG file where each of the rectangles is a pure shade of C, M, Y or K. Checked using the eyedropper tool in Adobe Photoshop.

[image: CMYK JJPEG output from Ghostscript]

Comment: I don't have photoshop, but the image is in RGB, don't it? It shouldn't be in CMYK?

Comment: I need the image in CMYK, if ghostscript just output RGB I'll need to convert it to CMYK and I'll have color loss.

Comment: No, the image is in CMYK, and when I open it in Photoshop it says its CMYK and allows me to view the components. What are you using to open the file ? Many viewers cannot handle CMYK well. You can always create a JPEG file yourself using the command line I posted, in case SO has done something to the image.

Comment: Yes, I just realized it happend to my images too, thank you for rule out a ghostscript problem. I think it's just how ImageMagick do things and there is no workaround. I'll try use ghostscript directly.